# How to fix scrlayer-scrpage / microtype kerning issue?

Tags: fonts, microtype, kerning, scrlayer-scrpage

I am experiencing a weird interaction between `scrlayer-scrpage` package from Koma Script and a custom `microtype` setting. I am using `scrartcl` class together with Minion Pro font and `scrlayer-scrpage`. I also use `microtype` to increase the kerning between apostrophe glyphs as the default kerning is a bit too narrow to my taste.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[french]{babel}
\PassOptionsToPackage{babel, kerning=true}{microtype}
\usepackage[loosequotes]{MinionPro}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\SetExtraKerning[ name     = french-custom,
   context  = french,
   unit     = space   ]
   { encoding = *}
   {
   ' ={100,200},
   ’ ={100,200}
   }


\begin{document}

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\end{document}
```

Here is what I am getting with pdfTex: in the first page, the kerning is correct on both fonts, regular and italic.

[image: First page]

However, on the following pages, the kerning correction is not added to the italic font despite being applied to the regular font.

[image: Following pages]

The issue disappears if I remove the package `scrlayer-scrpage`. However I really need `scrlayer-scrpage` to achieve a specific layout so this would be nice if there is a way to make it compatible with the kerning correction.

How can I fix this issue ? Thank for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not restricted to the usage of `scrlayer-scrpage` (or any other KOMA-Script package or KOMA-Script class). It also occurs after any temporary usage of `\slshape`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\PassOptionsToPackage{babel, kerning=true}{microtype}
\usepackage[loosequotes]{MinionPro}

\SetExtraKerning[ name     = french-custom,
   context  = french,
   unit     = space   ]
   { encoding = *}
   {
   ' ={100,200},
   ’ ={100,200}
}

\begin{document}

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage

{\slshape}% temporary and local usage of \slshape
l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\PassOptionsToPackage{babel, kerning=true}{microtype}
\usepackage[loosequotes]{MinionPro}

\SetExtraKerning[ name     = french-custom,
   context  = french,
   unit     = space   ]
   { encoding = *}
   {
   ' ={100,200},
   ’ ={100,200}
   }

\pagestyle{headings}% for headings article also uses \slshape, which is replaced by an italic shape automatically
\begin{document}

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage
l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage
l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage
l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\end{document}
```

have the same issue with

[image: font issue]

from the second page, but do not use any KOMA-Script package or class. It seems, that this is related to the font warning:

> ```
> LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/sl' in size <10> not available   
> (Font)              Font shape `T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/it' tried instead on input line 25.
> ```

`scrlayer-scrpage` uses `\slshape` as a default for the page head and foot (see element `pageheadfoot` in the manual).
However, as there is no slanted, you can explicitly replace the usage of the slanted font in `scrlayer-scrpage` by the usage of an italic font:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\PassOptionsToPackage{babel, kerning=true}{microtype}
\usepackage[loosequotes]{MinionPro}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalcolor\itshape}

\SetExtraKerning[ name     = english-custom,
   context  = english,
   unit     = space   ]
   { encoding = *}
   {
   ' ={100,200},
   ’ ={100,200}
}

\begin{document}

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\newpage

l'éléphant \textit{l'éléphant}

\end{document}
```

Note: This does not really solve the `\slshape` issue in general but the occur of this issue in using `scrlayer-scrpage`, because it avoids the implicit replacement of the slanted font by an italic one.

Comment: This is a very good dissection and (at least to me) surprising in two aspects: KOMA-script uses slanted?! And second: This is a bug of microtype, isn't it?

Comment: @KeksDose Yes, KOMA-Script uses slanted. As you understand German, see the note about the usage of `\slshape` in https://komascript.de/faq-voreinstellung. I do not known whether this is a *bug* in `microtype`, but IMHO it is an issue of `microtype` and LaTeX's font replacement mechanism.

Comment: This has been fixed in `microtype` v2.7d.